# getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS when installing the app in device, core graphic

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect

What i am doing is to draw a simple rectangle and set color for the painted area

```
   // Just added
    @interface Gradient () {
       CGColorRef  lightBlueColor;
   }
    @implementation Gradient

    -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
    {
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            self.backgroundColor   =   [UIColor lightGrayColor];
            NSLog(@"frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
            NSLog(@"bound is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.bounds));
            lightBlueColor         =   [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;

        }
        return self;
    }

    -(void) layoutSubviews {
        paperRect =   CGRectMake(10, 10, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
    }

    -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

        //Draw a retangle
        CGContextRef        context     =   UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightBlueColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, paperRect);  


    }
```

Below is what is displayed on the simulator

[image]

However, when I am trying to install on the device, I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS
[image]

**Question :**

why it does not work on the device. Did I make a mistake somewhere

Edit : I have just tried to modified lightBlueColor

> lightBlueColor              =   [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

Then I can run the app on the device. I dont get it at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** so you just ran into a memory management issue. In theory, in both of the cases, the program could have crashed. Why? Because as per the documentation, `-[UIColor lightBlueColor]` and its accompaining class methods return an autoreleased object. In practice, for optimization reasons, it's not true: in fact, they return the same alloc-initied singleton in order to save memory. This optimization is possible because they always return the same color. As the shared instance (singleton color) has been created without an autorelease, it doesn't suddenly get released when you wouldn't expect that, that's why the program worked. If Apple's programmers weren't smart enough to make this optimization, both programs would have crashed.

But in the second case, the `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` method cannot possibly have this optimization, since it's not guaranteed that it always returns the same color. (Imagine what would happen if you called it to obtain a red color first, then it cached it, then you wanted to obtain a blue color, but it would have returned the cached red one.) So it actually creates a new instance of a color and autoreleases it. But since you don't retain it, soon it gets deallocated because of the autorelease and thus its `CGColor` property is invalidated as well. So, there are three possible solutions:

One. I'd prefer this. Make the `lightBlueColor` instance variable an `UIColor` object and create it using

```
lightBlueColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a];
```

then just use its `CGColor` property for drawing.

Two. Similar to the first one, but you can create the color object as

```
lightBlueColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a] retain];
```

as well, however I'd say this is a wrong concept.

Three: you can make the UIColor object vanish in the deep well of autorelease pools, but keep the `CGColor` safe:

```
lightBlueColor = CGColorRetain([UIColor colorWithRed:r green:g blue:b alpha:a].CGColor);
```

In each case, you should pay attention to memory management in the `dealloc` method.

**Lesson learned:** instance variables aren't good for storing autoreleased objects. You want to alloc-init and release when appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I dont get it. the original lightBlueColor is defined as `lightBlueColor         =   [UIColor colorWithRed:105.0f/255.0f green:179.0f/255.0f blue:216.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0].CGColor;` and it is CGColorRef type though

Comment: @ttran so it runs or doesn't run on the device depending on merely whether you call `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:` or `blueColor`?

Comment: Some times the iOS Version produce the problem, because may be it is Depreciated in New iOS, Kindly check it

Comment: @PREMKUMAR neither of these methods is deprecated as of iOS 4, 5 and 6.

Comment: @H2CO3 : it does not run when I call `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`

Comment: @ttran how is your `lightBlueColor` is declared? Is it an instance variable? A property? A global variable?

Comment: @ttran You was lucky with the implementation by smart Apple engineers in the case of `lightBlueColor`, but you have been less lucky with the cannot-be-implemented-smarter behavior of `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:`. Wait a bit, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: thanks but still getting lost about what you were saying

Comment: @ttran I'm disappointed that an answer with no explanation and only the easy solution got accepted and 2 votes already while I was preparing my answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 : sorry H2CO3. I did not know that you were preparing your answer. I kept refreshing the page and did not see your answer until now. Just read your lastest answer and I am totally satisfied with it. Just update my vote....

Comment: @H2CO3 - Really? You downvote my answer, which I gave 24 minutes before your edit, because it's not as long as yours? I explained the problem, just more succinctly. I didn't know an answer had to cover every possible solution to be correct.

Comment: @ttran Thans. Long answers need to be written for a long time - I wrote I was preparing it.

Comment: @(H2CO3 and maddy) : thanks both of you again. green check for both :))

Answer (score 1):

Your issue appears to be one of memory management. You don't call `CGColorRetain` on **lightBlueColor** in your `init` method. It works for `UIColor blueColor` most likely because that color is some constant kept around by the OS. Your color isn't so it goes out of scope and gets deallocated.

Once you add that, don't forget to call `CFColorRelease` in `dealloc` or any other appropriate place as needed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I could do green check twice, I would do it for you as well.